# How can I paste line terminator with autohotkey in notepad?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I am trying to paste line terminator in autohotkey.I have following code:

```
...
    a & s::
    Clipboard := "[source,java]`n----`n" . "`n---- `n" 
    sleep 30
    Send, ^v
    sleep 30
    Return
```

When I press the hotkey this program sends to notepad this:

```
> [source,java]`n--------
```

Instead of this:

```
> [source,java]
> ----
> 
> ----
```

You can see that there is no newline.

I tried other notepad tools such as notepad++ this script works great but it didn't work for notepad. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Either use the newline symbol: `n as follows:

```
 Clipboard := "[source,java]`n----`n`n----`n"
 ClipWait
```

Or use a continuation section:

```
Clipboard := 
(
"[source,java]
----

----
"
)
ClipWait
```

And use ClipWait to make sure the clipboard has the data!

Hth,

Comment: Thanks. I already tried `n and but notepad cannot detect new lines.These codes work correctly(notepad++,atom...) except for notepad .

Comment: Hmm. Works in my Notepad.  Maybe something to do with code page or unicode settings?  Btw, why are you concatenating? Did you try my examples the way I have them?

Comment: Yes, I tried this way, maybe there is a problem in my notepad.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to Unix-like OS's, Windows requires *both a CR and an LF* for a line break.
Try this:

```
Clipboard := "[source,java]`r`n----`r`n" . "`r`n---- `r`n"
```

Your code worked on Notepad++ and Atom **only because** they recognize sole line feeds as line breaks.